# Using Javascript to redact IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

## Overview

I'm building a website that has two textareas `input` and `output`

The concept is fairly straight-forward I want to:

- Parse the input using regex to match any IPv4/IPv6 addresses
- Redact them to [IPv4], [IPv6] using .replace or any other method
- Display the output in `output`

I have it working perfectly for IPv4, I can paste in a huge block of text in and it redacts all IPv4 addresses as expected.

## The problem

The regex, or possibly the javascript replace function for IPv6 is not working correctly.

## HTML to recreate problem

```js
<html>
<head>
</head>
   <body>
   <div>
      <label for="input" class= "left">Input Text</label>
      <label for="output" class = "right">Obfuscated Text - Click Text to Copy</label>
      <span></span>
      <textarea id="input"></textarea>
      <textarea id="output"></textarea>
   </div>
   <br>
   <button onclick="obfuscate()">Obfuscate</button>
   <script>
      function obfuscate() {
         // Get the input and output textareas
         var input = document.getElementById("input");
         var output = document.getElementById("output");

         // Obfuscate the text in the input textarea
         var obfuscatedText = input.value.replace(/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g, "[IPv4]")
         var lines = obfuscatedText.split('\n')
         const modifiedLines = lines.map(line => line.replace(/\b(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))\b/,"[IPv6]"));

         // Set the value of the output textarea to the obfuscated text
         output.value = modifiedLines.join('\n');
      }
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

#### Notes

Originally for [IPv6] nothing was redacted, I read online somewhere that replace can't handle very large strings. So I broke it down into individual lines. This works better, but still doesn't replace all the matches.

#### Current Behavior

Given even a small `input` of

```
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:100::/64 {
    # Two addresses available to clients
    #  (the third client should get NoAddrsAvail)
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:100::10 3ffe:501:ffff:100::11;

    # Use the whole /64 prefix for temporary addresses
    #  (i.e., direct application of RFC 4941)
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: temporary;

    # Some /64 prefixes available for Prefix Delegation (RFC 3633)
    prefix6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: 3ffe:501:ffff:111:: /64;
}

# A second subnet behind a relay agent
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:101::/64 {
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:101::10 3ffe:501:ffff:101::11;

    # Override of the global definitions,
    # works only when a resource (address or prefix) is assigned
    option dhcp6.name-servers 3ffe:501:ffff:101:200:ff:fe00:3f3e;

}
```

It fails to redact all v6 addresses

Output:

```
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:100::/64 {
    # Two addresses available to clients
    #  (the third client should get NoAddrsAvail)
    range6 [IPv6]10 3ffe:501:ffff:100::11;

    # Use the whole /64 prefix for temporary addresses
    #  (i.e., direct application of RFC 4941)
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: temporary;

    # Some /64 prefixes available for Prefix Delegation (RFC 3633)
    prefix6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: 3ffe:501:ffff:111:: /64;
}

# A second subnet behind a relay agent
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:101::/64 {
    range6 [IPv6]10 3ffe:501:ffff:101::11;

    # Override of the global definitions,
    # works only when a resource (address or prefix) is assigned
    option dhcp6.name-servers [IPv6];

}
```

#### I suck at regex

I borrowed the regex to match IPv6 from [ihateregex.io](https://ihateregex.io/expr/ipv6/) site.

On their site when I test it with the same input sample from before, it matches all of the addresses perfectly so that's where I'm stuck.

There are 2 similar questions on SO, one is using php and the other is using python. If possible I would like to do this all in javascript so the text remains client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I borrowed the regex to match IPv6 from ihateregex.io site.

...but you added `\b` to that regex. For the `\b` at the start of the regex this is no problem, but for the *end* of the regex it is. The thing is that an IPv6 address may end with a colon. In that case `\b` will require that this final colon is followed by an alphanumerical! This is the reason why some IPv6 addresses in the text are not matched.

So... remove that `\b` at the end of the regex.

Secondly, you need to provide the `g` modifier if you expect more than one match.

And now it is not necessary to split the text into lines:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function obfuscate() {
  output.value = input.value
        .replace(/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b/g, "[IPv4]")
        .replace(/\b(([\da-f]{1,4}:){7}[\da-f]{1,4}|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,6}:[\da-f]{1,4}|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,2}|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,3}|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,4}|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,5}|[\da-f]{1,4}:((:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[\da-f]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[\da-f]{0,4}){0,4}%[\da-z]+|(::(ffff(:0{1,4})?:)?|([\da-f]{1,4}:){1,4}:)((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1?\d)?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1?\d)?\d))/g,"[IPv6]");
}

input.value = `subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:100::/64 {
    # Two addresses available to clients
    #  (the third client should get NoAddrsAvail)
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:100::10 3ffe:501:ffff:100::11;

    # Use the whole /64 prefix for temporary addresses
    #  (i.e., direct application of RFC 4941)
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: temporary;

    # Some /64 prefixes available for Prefix Delegation (RFC 3633)
    prefix6 3ffe:501:ffff:100:: 3ffe:501:ffff:111:: /64;
}

# A second subnet behind a relay agent
subnet6 3ffe:501:ffff:101::/64 {
    range6 3ffe:501:ffff:101::10 3ffe:501:ffff:101::11;

    # Override of the global definitions,
    # works only when a resource (address or prefix) is assigned
    option dhcp6.name-servers 3ffe:501:ffff:101:200:ff:fe00:3f3e;

}`;
obfuscate();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 10px 0 10px 0 }

textarea { width: 45vw; height: 75vh }
```

```html
<table>
   <tr><th>Input Text<button onclick="obfuscate()">Obfuscate</button></th><th>Obfuscated Text</th></tr>
   <tr><td><textarea id="input"></textarea></td><td><textarea id="output"></textarea></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: removing the "\b" still gives the same result as before.
I had forgotten that I added that in thinking the regex was only matching the first occurance in each line.

Comment: Yes, that is another issue, you must of course provide the `g` modifier to have more than one match.